# Define a one-parameter grant print_for (n), n represents the range over which the friend number will be printed

Tags: python

Define a one-parameter grant print_for (n), n represents the range over which the friend number will be printed. For n = 10,000 results, five pairs of friendly numbers: 220 and 284, 1184 and 1210, 2620 and 2924, 5020 and 5564, and 6232 and 6368.

```
from math import *
def sum_of_divisor (a):
pom = 1
for i in range (2, int (sqrt(a)) + 1):
    if a % i == 0:
        pom += i
        if i != a // i:
        pom += a // i
return pom

def friendly_n (a, b):
    result = "false"
    if(a == sum_of_divisor(b) and sum_of_divisor(a) == b):
        result = "true"
    return result
a = 284
b = 220 

def write_friendly(n)
```

I don't know how to write a function to print friendly numbers. 
Please help

Comment: What's the definition of friendly numbers? Maybe translate the function names to English, might be more understandable for the rest of us.

Comment: In number theory, friendly numbers are two or more natural numbers with a common abundancy index, the ratio between the sum of divisors of a number and the number itself. Two numbers with the same "abundancy" form a friendly pair; n numbers with the same "abundancy" form a friendly n-tuple.

Comment: I translated the function names to english

Comment: OK the translation really helps. So you want to pass to `friendly_n` a and b where a and b are between 2 to `n` and a is not b? Maybe with two nested for loops?

Comment: I have to write a program according to the command given above, and I don't know how to write a function that prints the friend numbers

Comment: the above program works, but I don't know how to write the last function that prints the friendly numbers

Comment: the function I need to write starts with `def write_friendly(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comments, perhaps this helps:

```
if friendly_n(a, b) == 'true': # a and b are friendly, according to friendly_n
    string_to_print = str(a) + ' and ' + str(b) + ' are friendly'
    print(string_to_print)
```

?